# Inserting Russian characters into table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I get the same result when I try to insert Russian characters to table. The result is always

```
????????? – ???????? ?????????? ?????? ????
```

I tried `nvarchar`, but still the same. `Varchar` with a collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS` and `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS` also gives the same result. How to handle that? I tried to insert on Management Studio; manually it works, but when it comes to Entity Framework it doesn't.

Btw, I don't want `nvarchar` for certain reasons!

Comment: I use `nvarchar` throughout my projects so I'd like to hear the reasons you do not want to use it in case they might be relevant to me.

Comment: The **only** real solution ***IS*** using `NVARCHAR` (only that is Unicode-based), and inserting values using the `N'...'` prefix when doing T-SQL based inserts

Comment: `nvarchar` didn't work. What if I change the collation of the database? What kind of effect on other tables will it have?

Comment: Moreover, when I changed the database collation to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS` (column was still `varchar`) it didn't work, but when I changed the column to `nvarchar` then it worked.

Comment: ***HOW*** did you use `Nvarchar`? If you define a column as `nvarchar`, but upon inserting you're **not** using the `N'...'` prefix, then of course it won't work. Collation has nothing to do with the question of whether or not the column can hold unicode strings (nvarchar) or not.

Comment: Well, I'm not inserting it manually, EF does the work.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, And was searching for a way to change the query string to include charset=utf8 and all kinds of workarounds.

The issue in the end was that the EDMX model had been created BEFORE the change to nvarchar was made.

It does not magically update the model, so if your EDMX file was generated before the change in the DB was made the nvarchar you have to regenerate it.

After that simple change, ?????? became привет without any problems.

[image]

Comment: I already found a solution. Your's one also works great. Thnx!